# How to center parts of a list efficiently with CSS [Img Inside]

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop, centering

[image: Efficent Centering Problem]

the problem is, i know i can center all the three objects in the list correctly using 3 while loops with CSS, but i also know than use 3 whiles loops for something like that is a waste of resources

Also i love if the solution includes order them relative to the "white page" too, which, 3 while loops aproach seems to archieve too

so the question is, how will be the best CSS aproach to do that without the need of call three While loops?
(saving responsiveness)

UPDATE: The thing is, the products, types & Price are all almacenated in a database so to make an easy control and administration of all of them at once, and show them on the list to the people who visit them easier.

The Other stuff, the Styles and the "hidden" is because that divs are the black & white squares, which will actualy be white if there is some of the product remaining, and will be black if's not the case.

The Code related are this ones:

Style.CSS

```
#TextTitl {
    font: 38px/1.1em "Fredericka the Great",fantasy;
    color: #5D463E;
}
#stylProdct {
    background-color:#fff;
    width:75%;
}
.whiteAvbly
{
display:hidden;
background-color:#ffffff;
border: 3px solid #333333;
height:15px;
width:15px;
float:left;
left:12.5%;
position:relative;
}
.blackAvbly
{
display:hidden;
background-color:#380807;
border: 3px solid #333333;
height:15px;
width:15px;
float:left;
left:12.5%;
position:relative;
}
#doscinco {
    float:left;
    left:25%;
    position:relative;
}
#cincuenta {
    float:left;
    left:50%;
    position:relative;
}
#sietecinco {
    float:left;
    left:75%;
    position:relative;
}
```

verduras.php

```
<?php 
include('conection.php');
echo '<center><section id="stylProdct">';
    $Verd = 'Verduras';
    $smt = $con->prepare("select * from prodcts WHERE Type = :Verduras Order by PrdName ASC");
    $smt->bindParam(':Verduras', $Verd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $smt->execute();
    echo '<br /><br /><H2 id="TextTitl">VERDURAS</H2><br />';
while ($smr = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) 
    {
        $idf = $smr['Availblty'];
        $ids = (int) $idf;
        echo'<p>';
    if($ids > 0)
        { 
    echo '<style>.whiteAvbly{display:show;}</style><div class="whiteAvbly"></div>';
        }
    else
        {
    echo '<style>.blackAvbly{display:show;}</style><div class="blackAvbly"></div>';
        } 
        echo '<div id="doscinco">'.nl2br($smr['PrdName']).'</div><div id="cincuenta">'.nl2br($smr['SellType']).'</div><div id="sietecinco">$'.nl2br($smr['Cost']).'</div></p><br />
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />';
    }
echo '</section></center>';
?>
```

Html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clone Dinka</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chelsea+Market' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqwdinka.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mullet"></div>
    <header>
        <div id="BigSist"><img id="hermana" src="imago/upper_logo.png"/>​<p class="white">tel</p><p class="black">(+56 9) 65637350</p></div>
        <img id="logoc" src="imago/logo.png"/>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">​
                <p class="white" id="Tralala">DESPACHO DIRECTO A TU PUERTA</p>
                <span>Haz tu pedido / Cotiza</span>
            </div>
            <ul id="cont">
                <li id="than"><a href="main">INICIO</a></li>
                <li class="menuHead"><a href="#">PRODUCTOS</a>
                    <ul id="cont">
                        <li><a href="verduras">Verduras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Frutas">Frutas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="MoteconHuesillo">Mote con Huesillo</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ComoComprar">¿COMO COMPRAR?</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contacto">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--"http://lorempixel.com/g/470/300"-->
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //initial
  $('#content').load('main.php');
  $('body').load().css('background-image', 'url(' + 'imago_tesla/fondo0.jpg' + ')');


  //handle menu clicks
  $('ul#cont li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(page + '.php');

    var pageImages = {
      'main': 'imago_tesla/fondo0.jpg',
      'verduras': 'imago_tesla/fondo4.jpg',
      'Frutas': 'imago_tesla/fondo4.jpg',
      'MoteconHuesillo': 'imago_tesla/fondo4.jpg',
      'ComoComprar': 'imago_tesla/fondo2.jpg',
      'Contacto': 'imago_tesla/fondo.jpg'
    }

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + pageImages[page] + ')');
  });
});
```

That must be

Please, feel free to ask for clarification, comment, answer, suggest, etc... all the help feedback wherever's the nature of this would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is not what you asked for, but why don't you use a table?

Comment: Or use CSS table, could you post your HTML rather than PHP code?

Comment: The browser sees HTML, CSS works on HTML; so why have you posted php?

Comment: Thanks to all of you, the thing is, the products, types & Price are all almacenated in a database so to make an easy control and administration of all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best use with `<table>`s, but if must use `<div>` either you set specific sizes (is not the best option) or, you surround each column in a separate `<div>` example:

```
<!-- Column products -->
<div>
    <!-- Product lines -->
    <div>Product 1</div>
    <div>Product 2</div>
    <div>Product 3</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<!-- Column units -->
<div>
    <!-- Product lines -->
    <div>kg</div>
    <div>l</div>
    <div>2/kg</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<!-- Column prices -->
<div>
    <!-- Product lines -->
    <div>800$</div>
    <div>200$</div>
    <div>342$</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

And set your formatings to make them inline

Comment: Yeah, but the idea is automatize the thing for work straight with the database, thanks for the try, and i update the question so to avoid this confusion in the future

Comment: It's easy to work that out in php, I just put it there the way it should output in html. It would work if inside the while, you set a var (array if you need an arbitrary number of columns) setting the html AS TEXT to each var/column and after the loop echoing them in place. Just tell me if you need a php example based on what you have up there using only one while loop.

Comment: I'll try it on the While loop, it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Putting it in columns rather than rows might be an easier solution, but it will come back to haunt you if you want to do some SEO. If you don't need that, you'll be fine with that solution

Answer (score 1):

As I already said, I suggest using a table, after all this is the type of data tables are meant for.

If changing your markup is not a solution, here's a quick hack, based on the fact that apparently you want every field occupying 25% of the total width. Just change the last part of your CSS to:

```
#doscinco {
    float:left;
    left:25%;
    width:25%;
    position:relative;
}
#cincuenta {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
#sietecinco {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

But there are still other problems in there:

- Your HTML will have several tags with the same ID, because you're using IDs in a loop.
- You are repeating style definitions that you could put in a separate class and reuse that class to keep your definitions easier to maintain
- You're using `<center>`. It's better to put all style information in your CSS.
- Last but not least: `display:show` is not valid CSS and making those 2 classes hidden hidden just to unhide them is superfluous anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work your answer, thanks for the try, and about the points: 1) yeah, it was intended to be that way :) i update the question to avoid confusions with that. 2) good point, i'll try that when i solve this ;) 3) True, but <center> seems to avoid several centering business at least for me, but i'll give it a try. 4) is explayed in the update for the divs.
Thanks for the try

Comment: How does it fail? As for the other stuff, well, if it was designed to be broken, than who am I to tell you that it's broken? ;)

Comment: All of them just stack one over another, not really putting themselfs one 25% distance from the other, but the tables must says was part of the answer indeed, but not the complete solution. Thanks a lot for the answers and for the help, have a nice day!

Comment: JFTR: The CSS part of the solution was using "width" instead of left, floats or right.